# Channel data properties : Carousel?

Tags: c#, botframework

I want to get media from a website. That media should be listed something like Carousel card template.

With loop i want to store all the media in one object.

Have this :

```
 resultMessage.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
                resultMessage.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                var fbObject = new object[activities.Count];
    while (!stop)
    {
     if (activities[counter].MediaTypeValue != (int)MediaTypeEnum.Video)
                        {
                            fbObject[counter] = new
                            {
                                type = "image",
                                payload = new object[]
                                {
                                        new
                                        {
                                           url = activities[counter].DocumentPath
                                        },
                                }
                            };
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fbObject[counter] = new
                            {
                                type = "video",
                                buttons = new object[]
                                {
                                        new
                                        {
                                            type = "web_url",
                                            url = activities[counter].DocumentPath,
                                            title = activities[counter].FirstName + " " + activities[counter].LastName + " posted " + BotHelper.UserPosted(activities[counter].MediaTypeValue),
                                             webview_height_ratio = "compact",
                                            messenger_extensions = true
                                        }
                                }
                            };
                        }
  counter--;
                    if (counter < 0)
                        stop = true;

    }


 resultMessage.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new { fbObject }); ;
                await context.PostAsync(resultMessage);
```

But Facebook messenger does not render it as "carousel".

Any idea how to show object like Carousel type of card ?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook will render the carousel if you have Attachments in your message. Your attachments collection is empty and you are sending channel data info, which won't be rendered as a carousel.

Both Image and Video are supported attachments in `BotFramework` and you can just use the available rich cards instead of using channel data to send them to the user.

Take a look to the [RichCards sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-RichCards) to understand how to create each of the supported cards. Also, you might also want to review the [Carousel sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-CarouselCards).

Finally, it's always a good idea to review the documentation around attachments and Rich cards. See [this](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html) and [this](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/attachments/#navtitle).